# Is there a programmatic variable for borders around windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am trying to set the maximum size a windows form can be set to, which may be different depending on what data needs to be displayed.

Is there a way to get the size of the borders around your windows form without having to calculate it yourself?

Currently, I have used the difference of the `Size` and `ClientSize` properties, like:

```
windowDressingWidth = this.Size.Width - this.ClientSize.Width;
windowDressingHeigth = this.Size.Height - this.ClientSize.Height;
```

Which works, but seems a bit backwards.  Is there some sort of `SystemInformation` or similar variable that stores this (like `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` does for the scroll bar height).

The closest I've found is SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize, which is 8 on my system, and that is half of my windowDressingWidth (16), so that might be for each side.

In the case of this program, it has no menu, but (on my system) has the aero borders all around, and the thicker one on top for the title and the Maximize, Minimize, and close controls.

Comment: I think your calculation is farly the most reliable choice, because for just one quick example one could have bigger font-size set in Windows which could effect this "global" value.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to let the end user decide what's the maximum size for their windows as opposed to hardcoding it yourself. If you set your maximum size to something like 1900 x 800 or the like, think what will happen when somebody with a screen resolution of 8000 x 5000 tries to use your application. However, achieving full resolution independence in winforms is really cumbersome and that's why it's also recommended to avoid using winforms and create your applications using relevant, current technology instead.

Comment: @HighCore In this case, the data is being shown in a `DataGridView`, and I am limitting the size so that I can limit the size of the `DataGridView` to not show the unused area of the `DataGridView`.  Currently, that maximumWidth = DataGridViewWidth.Location.X + DataGridViewWidth + windowDressing + margin, where margin is a hard coded "this far away from the clientsize's edge number".  So I calculate the maximum via what it needs to show, so if they load a file that only needs the window to be 900x600 on that 8000x5000 screen, it should still only show 900x600.

Comment: @Xantham which is really bad, since your application is going to look like a tiny square in the top-left corner on the screen. You should really make your UI resolution independent.

Comment: @HighCore This should take into account larger fonts used for that higher resolution, since that will be part of that DataGridViewWidth calculation, or other things to make a window still readable on the 8000x5000 screen.  I would like to learn WPF eventually, but this is what can currently do.  Part of this rigmarole is dealing with some shortcomings of the DataGridView though.

Comment: @HighCore So, I think I AM making this rsolution independant by calculating how much space is necessary to display all cells of the DataGridView, by doing the calculation `var DataGridViewWidth = calibrationDataGridView.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);` .  If I am wrong in this though, I would definitely prefer learning what would make this more resolution independent.

Comment: There *is* a way to get this information from system parameters, but it starts getting rather complicated. The way you're doing it is the simplest way, and if it works, that's what I'd keep doing.

Answer (score 2):

The only other one you could need is SystemInformation.CaptionHeight

I should note that this is a bad idea.  Always set the ClientSize property instead, that automatically ensures that the window is large enough to provide the client area you need.  Also the way the designer works, when you set the form's Size property in the Properties window then the designer actually records the ClientSize value in the InitializeComponent() method.  Which ensures your form still works on another machine where the user changed the preferences.  Like the caption font and button sizes.  Or a machine that has Aero turned off.